# Webrequest executing twice in a row

Tags: c#, httpwebrequest

Can anyone help me to figure out why this web request is executing twice in a row?

```
private void intoPrtg()
    {       
        WebRequest request = WebRequest.Create("data");     

        ServicePointManager.CertificatePolicy = new MyPolicy();

        HttpWebResponse response = (HttpWebResponse)request.GetResponse();

        Console.WriteLine(response.StatusDescription);

        Stream dataStream = response.GetResponseStream();

        StreamReader reader = new StreamReader(dataStream);

        string responseFromServer = reader.ReadToEnd();

        reader.Close();
        dataStream.Close();
        response.Close();
    }

// using this for accepting ssl certificate. 

public class MyPolicy : ICertificatePolicy
    {
        public bool CheckValidationResult(ServicePoint srvPoint,
          X509Certificate certificate, WebRequest request,
          int certificateProblem)
        {
            //Return True to force the certificate to be accepted.
            return true;
        }
    }
```

I am calling it from the Main method. Then when I check data on web, I see that it send data twice in a row.

Answer (score 0):

Try to set PreAuthenticate property on the request to TRUE.

Comment: Tried to use that, still execute twice in a row